# How to delete duplicate SMS?

Tags: cyanogenmod, sms

After unlucky using some SMS backup tool I have the duplicates of all my SMS.
So question is which way better to delete them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [BackupSMS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cz.kamma.backupsms) . It claims to remove duplicates. I've not tried it personally.

Make sure you take backup before trying it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Back up and Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore&hl) to manually and multi select all the SMS's you want to delete.

Comment: I have about 5484 SMS and ~ 40% of them are duplicates so manual removal is not the solution.