# How can I delete duplicated SMS?

Tags: sms

I have a lot of duplicated SMS on my Android 7.1.2 Phone, because of the app "SMS Backup & Restore". I would like to delete redundant SMSs. How can I do that? Before actually doing it, I would like to inspect the would-be result.

What I tried:

- In [How to delete duplicate SMS?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/54114/how-to-delete-duplicate-sms/54116), it says that "SMS Backup & Restore" has an option to not import duplicates. I could not find that option.
- Also it said to check out "BackupSMS", but the app does not seem to offer the option to check out the results.
- After reading http://blog.radj.me/removing-duplicates-sms-backup-restore-xml-android, I looked at https://github.com/radj/AndroidSMSBackupRestoreCleaner and tried the expanded version https://github.com/hameerabbasi/AndroidSMSBackupRestoreCleaner. But after inspecting the results, I got the impression the script also deleted messages that were not duplicates. I am pretty glad I was able to inspect the results via Linux tools, showing me that my instinct to be able to check out the results was correct.
- Also coming from the blog, I found the app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.venomvendor.sms.deduplicate (Source at https://github.com/VenomVendor/DeduplicateSMS), but this also does not show what SMS are going to be deleted.
- In the thread https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidQuestions/comments/3ecq7z/how_to_delete_duplicate_sms_after_restore/, it was suggested to use Google Hangouts. I do not have (or want to use) something like Google Hangouts.

Comment: Not tried myself, but there's an app called [Deduplicate SMS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.venomvendor.sms.deduplicate) which should do exactly that.

Comment: @Izzy: That app has already been mentioned by me and it has rather mixed reviews. As I mentioned, it lacks the option to inspect what the changes will be - in other words, which messages are going to be deleted. I am not sure if I can trust the app.

Answer (score 1):

just found that on "SMS Backup + Restore" the option to not restore duplicates is present when you actually go to restore, under "advanced options" it's actually down as "disable duplicate check (faster restore) and is by default set to "off" so it will check.
Having just run it myself, I can confirm it does work (or at least has for me)